# Display articles related to a custom field on a page

Tags: loop, page-template, post-meta

I have a little problem to display some articles related to a parent page. I explain.

On the first hand I have a page with a model template. On the wordpress editor part, I create a custom meta field call "cat_page". This meta must be the same as the article related (view more below). This template has a classic loop to display to content of the page :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

and below I need to display the articles who have the same category name as the page.

```
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, "cat_page", true) == the_category() ) : ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

It's only what I think it should look, because I have tried several things but I don't know how to proceed.

Image (if it can help) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQwZh.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you adjust your words well to make it more understandable? its really not clear now :)

Comment: Sorry it was a bit hard to be really clear, but the problem is solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you have a page template, and you want to use this page template as a category archive.

The term to show is in a page meta field with key 'cat_page'.

If I'm right, in this page template use:

```
the post(); // being a singular page the 'while' stuff is useless
the_content(); // this will show the page content

$cat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cat_page', true ); // get the category to display

if ( $cat ) { // if category is setted in page custom field
   $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=' . $cat ); // run the custom query
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); // run the custom loop

     // your post loop code goes here

   }
   wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the post data after the custom query
}
```

Pleas note that to make this work in the custom meta `'cat_page'` you should put the category **slug** (not the category name).

Comment: Thanks, that's was perfectly what I was looking for, and for sure, I put the slug of category name. :)